# Getting call stack during call of a specific function

Tags: auto-save

An automatic save is triggered (from some hook in some of my extensions) directly after a buffer is modified and I can't find the reason for it. The mode `auto-save-`mode is not enabled in the buffer where the auto save happens. Is there a way to detect which top-function (hook) that is calling a specific function? In my case `save-buffer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say `M-x debug-on-entry RET save-buffer RET`.